# 2005 Honda DX 4dr 5spd - Gauge Cluster and Int Wipers not working, why?

Tags: honda, electrical, civic

OK, I have a 2005 Honda Civic DX 4dr Sedan with a 5 speed manual Transmission, Standard everything, no power windows, A/C, plain basic setup.
So the other day suddenly my Gauge cluster stops working, it still lights up and all other lights work as well like the turn signal indicators, but the gauges themselves are dead and parked in the "zero" position, also my intermittent wipers don't work, but the regular speed and fast speed work. This all happened a few days ago. My question is this ... is there a controller unit that operates these functions? That maybe could be "flashed", or does the gauge cluster unit have control of this? I tried to check for a ground wire or something loose, but couldn't see anything. Any suggestions would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: Did you pull the cluster? There should be a couple ground splices under the cluster for both the wiper and instrument cluster. The multiplex unit/under dash fuse box has a hand in both systems, but AFAIK a flash probably wouldn't help your situation.

Comment: Like @Ben said, you should pull the cluster or have someone do it. It could be a bad or loose ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, So Thank you to those that tried to answer my question.
I did find the problem, I've had this car for only 1 year and
never had any issues so when this came up I was forced to look at
the systems etc, thanks to Ben's answer I didn't even know that
this car had 2 separate fuse panels one under the hood and one
hidden nicely under the front dash, under the steering wheel, behind
a wiring harness. But there it is. A simple fuse. It controls the
Gauges on the cluster but not the lights on the cluster, it is also
for the intermittent wiper timer, but not for the wipers themselves.
Whew, some intense wiring going on in this vehicle. But it appears that
Honda has a fuse for almost EVERYTHING.

---

PROBLEM SOLVED !!